# Export excel file to textpad each cell delimited by '|'

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

MS Excel export allows a csv (comma delimited) export. Is it possible to export my files from excel to .txt or csv files *(all the cells in my excel file)* delimited by "|" (without the quotes) instead of commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In MS Excel 2007, you would go to your options, and visit the detailed settings tab. Uncheck the box for using system delimiters (which should be showing the comma character). Then, just enter the pipe character or whatever you want as your new default column delimiter. With this setting change, the pipe character will be used instead of the comma when you export as CSV. You should have a look at [this page](http://www.ehow.com/how_5900012_save-excel-spreadsheet-pipe-delimited.html).

Comment: That page worked out fine, I changed in Windows 7 from Control Panel > Region and Language settings > Formats > Additional settings > List Separator. In that box I changed it from "," to "|". Thanks, the page link at the end of your post did the trick